# Javascript CustomEvent detail not getting passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to create a custom Javascript event. The event works and fires correctly, but the 'detail' object that I'm passing it is not available.

Here's the code I'm using to create and dispatch the event:

```
var double_tap = new CustomEvent("doubleTap", {
    detail: {
        hello: 'world'  
    },
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});

this.dispatchEvent(double_tap);
```

Then I'm using jQuery to add an event listener to the body:

```
$('body').on('doubleTap', function( e ) { 
    console.log(e);
});
```

It does fire, and the console log happens, but unfortunately the log only outputs the event details including bubbles and cancelable properties, but never the 'detail' object, so that information is not accessible.

Here's a jsbin as example, I'm creating the event on the click event of the body so you can see the console; http://jsbin.com/looseroots/6

I would like to be able to get the data from the 'detail' object when the event is fired. What am I doing wrong? I have tested this in Chrome, and Safari on iOS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to access the originalEvent property for the details

```
console.log(e.originalEvent.detail);
```

Comment: So simple, yet none of the documentation that I could find explaining the CustomEvent method pointed this out. Thank you!

Comment: This is not really a CustomEvent issue, I believe jQuery wraps a DOM event into its own Event object.. (i'm no jQuery expert so I could be wrong)

Comment: Can also add data arguments to jQuery handlers if prefer to keep all code within jQuery realm. `$('body').on('doubleTap', function( e, arg1, arg2 )`

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I shall refrain from using jQuery. I was just using it out of convenience while I tested. element.addEventListener wil do the job nicely! Useful info!

Answer (score 21):

```
obj.addEventListener("eventName", function(e) {
console.log(e.your_property)
})

var event = new CustomEvent("eventName");
event.your_property = { key: "value" };

obj.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can create properties in your CustomEvent, when you dispatch you are sending it.

Comment: THIS is gold! :-)

Comment: Great! it is working. But i don't know why event.detail is not working i.e., when we pass object in detail it is not found in listener.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following commit: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/a90ff8c8c79bfcc32afd340a12f016f20a31d8b6

This fix is in jQuery's `compat` branch and should be fixed as of jQuery 3.0.