# jQuery destroying `detail` of custom Polymer events in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, polymer, dom-events

I am defining a Polymer component in Meteor that does a custom `fire`:

```
<polymer-element name="tm-card">
  <template>
    ... content ...
    <paper-button data-rating="good" on-tap="{{rated}}" flex raised> Good! </paper-button>
    <paper-button data-rating="easy" on-tap="{{rated}}" flex> Easy! </paper-button>
  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer({
    rated: function (event, detail, sender) {
      var rating = sender.dataset.rating;
      this.fire('rated', {rating: rating});
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

This seems to work great and I can catch the event in Meteor:

```
<template name='reviewItem'>
  <tm-card>
    <p class="question">{{question}}</p>
    <p class="answer">{{answer}}</p>
  </tm-card>
</template>


Template.reviewItem.events
  'rated': (evt, tmpl) ->
    console.log 'item rated'
    console.log evt.detail # undefined
    console.log evt.originalEvent.detail # {rating: "easy"}
```

But as you can see the event detail is lost (in the "outer" event). The outer event is a `jQuery.event` and the originalEvent is the `CustomEvent` that is fired by Polymer.

The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) state that:

"The following properties are also copied to the event object, though some of their values may be undefined depending on the event:

... detail, ..."

But the docs don't say how custom event types are handled.

- Is this normal jQuery behaviour?
- Is Meteor wrapping the events in `jQuery.event` for my convenience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question: [Javascript CustomEvent detail not getting passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333683/javascript-customevent-detail-not-getting-passed/28336674#28336674)

Then I found the following commit: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/a90ff8c8c79bfcc32afd340a12f016f20a31d8b6

This fix is in jQuery's `compat` branch and should be fixed as of jQuery 3.0, so I'll answer my own question for now.