# How can I pass custom object to a CustomEvent() using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use vanilla javascript to dispatch a custom event. Along with the event, I would like to pass a custom object.

Here is what I have done

```
document.addEventListener('abcAppended', function (e) {
     console.log(e.el); // write the custom object to the console
});

var wrapper = document.getElementById('abc');
if (wrapper) {
    // do something with wrapper
   
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('abcAppended', {
        el: wrapper // I tried to add custom object here
    }));
}
```

But the above write `undefined` to the console. How can I correctly pass an object and access it using a listener.

Comment: You should review [documentation for the `CustomEvent` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent). What you pass to the constructor as the second object is not what is returned as the event object in the listener.

Comment: I think you need to pass `detail` into the options object. Try using `detail: wrapper`?

Comment: A note for older browsers, and older versions of jQuery: [Javascript CustomEvent detail not getting passed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13333683/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firing and capturing custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057223/firing-and-capturing-custom-events)

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you. `detail` worked!